# Javascript Document.getElementById returning null

Tags: javascript, ajax, razor, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC and AJAX so this is probably a simple mistake I am making but using the code below, I am getting the following error trying to `getElementById("txtCount").value`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h5 style="font-weight:bold;">Parameters</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" id="parameters">
                <form class="form-horizontal" id="frmParameters">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtCount" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Repeat</label>
                        <input type="number" min="1" max="100" step="1" id="txtCount" value="@Model.Count" class="input-sm col-sm-7" />
                    </div>
                    @if (Model.Grammar.SupportsMaxLength)
                    { 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="txtMaxLength" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Max Length</label>
                            <input type="number" min="1" max="100" step="1" id="txtMaxLength" value="@Model.MaxLength" class="input-sm col-sm-7" />
                        </div>
                    }                        
                    <button name="btnGenerate" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="Generate();">Generate</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function Generate() {
    var data = { count: document.getElementById("txtCount").value, maxLength: document.getElementById("txtMaxLength").value };
    }
</script>
```

If I change:

```
    var data = { count: document.getElementById("txtCount").value, maxLength: document.getElementById("txtMaxLength").value };
```

to:

```
    var data = { count: document.getElementById("txtCount").value};
```

I don't get the error anymore.

Comment: is the value null or are you getting Cannot read property 'value' of null error?

Comment: @Deep value will never be null, would be empty string if no value set or user input

Comment: I'm getting 'Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at Generate'

Comment: @charlietfl not sure about that. C# do have nullable int concept

Comment: eleemnt clearly exists in html shown...problem must be elsewhere. Creat a [mcve] demo

Comment: @Deep what does `C#` have to do with dom methods or element properties?

Comment: value="@Model.Count"

Comment: @Deep even if it output *"null"* it would be evaluated as a string in dom and would not throw js error

Comment: yes that was i asking if the value is printed null or a js error was thrown

Comment: value coming from server might be null or empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. I think you are getting the error when your code tries to execute this line

`document.getElementById("txtMaxLength").value`

Because in your view you are rendering this element when some `if` condition returns `true`. So it is possible that your view does not have this input element at all and you are trying to read that! (Check the view source of the page and search for input with `txtMaxLength` id.

The best solution is to check it exists before trying to read the value.

```
var data = {
              id: "@Model.Id",
              count: document.getElementById("txtCount").value,
              maxLength: null  // or whatever default value you want
            };
if (document.getElementById("txtMaxLength")) {
    data2.maxLength = document.getElementById("txtMaxLength").value;
}
```

Or if you are using jQuery library, it is easy

```
var data = {
              id: "@Model.Id",
              count: $("#txtCount").val(),
              maxLength:$("#txtMaxLength").val()
          };
```

Comment: OP said he got error on getElementById("txtCount").value

Comment: **I'm getting 'Cannot read property 'value' of null at Generate'**

Comment: @Lance also means you were getting error on different element than mentioned in question

Comment: It is the same line of code which has both the bad guy and good guy. So i assume he thought it is the first one